# How to apply result of order by clause from subquery to main query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables which are linked by column named `MID`.
I want to fetch name from 1st table but the sequence is mentioned in 2nd table.
My query is as follows:

```
select name from table1 where MID in(select MID from table2 where CID="100" ORDER BY sequenceNum);
```

If i only run the query mentioned inside brackets then i get the data ordered by sequence.
But the above query is fetching the data from db as it is and not arranging it in sequence. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this shoukld do the trick...

```
SELECT name FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON Table2.MID = table1.MID AND CID="100" 
ORDER BY
  table2.sequenceNum
```

Comment: name i am having in 3 different languages and the query which u suggested is taking order as per sequence number but instead of name 1, name 2, name 3 its showing name3,2 and then 1

Comment: If what you said in your first post about the inner query shoing in the correct order, then it should work.
Please show output showing  table1.Name, table2.Mid, table2.sequenceNum

Answer (score 0):

You want merge two tables and order results by merged table:

```
SELECT table1.name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table2.MID = table1.MID)
WHERE table2.CID = "100"
ORDER BY table2.sequenceNum;
```

or

```
SELECT table1.name
FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table2.MID = table1.MID AND table2.CID = "100")
ORDER BY table2.sequenceNum;
```

If you want get field from concrete table, use table prefix like `table1.name`